# Use section sign § as cut delimiter

Tags: bash, sh, cut

I thought this would be pretty straight forward

```
echo "1§2" | cut -d § -f 2
```

should give "2", right? But whatever I try

```
echo "1§2" | cut -d § -f 2 
echo "1§2" | cut -d \§ -f 2
echo "1§2" | cut -d "§" -f 2 
echo "1§2" | cut -d '§' -f 2
```

I always get

```
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
```

Does someone know why? § does not seem to be a special character in any way.

Comment: compare `echo 'a' | xxd -c 1` to `echo '§' | xxd -c 1`.  welcome to the wonderful world of Unicode :)

Answer (score 1):

§ seems to be no single byte character as pointed out in the comment [Use section sign § as cut delimiter](https://superuser.com/questions/1181190/use-section-sign-as-cut-delimiter#comment1710105_1181190)

`cut` can only work with single byte characters

related https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163725